# Microsoft Graph create event on particular calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can create an event, and I can create a calendar.  How do I create an event on a particular calendar?  The Calendar section of the Event JSON is read only according to the spec.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the URL needed.  Very handy typeahead on the Graph Explorer helped find how to form this:

GET
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[User ID]/calendars/[Calendar ID]/events
Lists the events on this calendar

POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[User ID]/calendars/[Calendar ID]/events

Adds a new event.

Hope this helps anyone else.